Qdrant : How to leverage recommende end points
I am exploring recommend points to build a recommendation system. I am looking for few examples around these endpoint and secondly when we are providing positive and negative examples vectors, how can we provide multiple positive and negative examples. I am referring following document: https://api.qdrant.tech/api-reference/search/recommend-points . Thanks in advance.
Lastly, Is there any framework which helps to build recommendation system.

POST /collections/{collection_name}/points/query
{
    "query": {
        "recommend": {
            "positive": [vector1, vector2],
            "negative": [vector3, vector4],
            "strategy": "average_vector"
        }
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
